# Concatenate multiple string using string interpolation in c#

Tags: c#, string

The code I tried:

```
public void ConcatIntegers() {
  string s = "";

  for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    s += i.ToString();
  }

  Console.WriteLine($ "{s}");
  Console.Read();
}
```

In Above method + is used to concatenate multiple values but I was looking for anyway except join, aggregate, concatenate function, instead of `+`  symbol I want to use string `interpolation ($)` directly which store concatenated string into a string variable.

```
string s = "";

for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  // Some code which use string interpolation to 
  // concatenat multiple string and that result is stored in s 
  // variable.
}

Console.WriteLine($ "{s}");
Console.Read();
```

Comment: What language is this? I know of no language which has the keyword `Public` (with that casing!). Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Tushar What is your question?

Comment: @prashant ,We use + operator to concatenate multiple strings which i shown in "The code I tried". Instead of that code I want to use string interpolation which helps concatenate multiple string and my code will be readable.

Comment: Use string builder to concat strings due to huge performance difference.

Comment: String interpolation doesn't concatenate, it *formats* a string with parameters. In essense it's an easier way to write `String.Format`. Since `s` is a string using interpolation here is meaningless

Comment: @Tushar - please check my answer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> except join, aggregate, concatenate function, instead of + symbol I want to use string interpolation ($)
>
> directly which store concatenated string into a string variable...

simply try:

```
string result = string.Empty;
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) result = $"{result}{i}";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) since if you do that a lot it is much faster
Use [AppendFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string var1   = "abcd";
string var2   = "efgh";
sb.AppendFormat("example: {0}, {1}", var1, var2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use String Builder to concatenate the string:

Your code after changes:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

string s = "";
sb.Append(s);
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
   sb.Append(i);
}

Console.WriteLine(sb);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *concatenate*, let's try [string.Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings) or `string.Join`; with a little help of *Linq* (in order to get rid of `for` loop) we'll get

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  // static: we don't use "this" in the method
  public static void ConcatIntegers() {
    // Concatenate range of 0..5 integers: "012345"
    Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(Enumerable
      .Range(0, 6))); // 6 - we want 6 numbers: 0..5

    Console.Read();
  }
```

In case you want to use some *format*, *string interpolation* etc. add `Select`:

```
 public static void ConcatIntegers() {
   // "000102030405" since we apply "d2" format (each number reprsented with 2 digits)
   Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(Enumerable
     .Range(0, 6)
     .Select(i => $"{i:d2}"))); // each item in 2 digits format

   Console.Read();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on using string interpolation in string.join

```
        string type1 = "a,b,c";
        string[] type2 = new string[3] { "a", "b", "c" };
        
        string result = string.Join(",", $"'{x}'");
```

In both cases, the output should be 'a','b','c'

how to use string.Join() with string interpolation for array of strings